# Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY) (found version "1.2.11")

Tags: zlib, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install the tool [shmutzi](https://github.com/grenaud/schmutzi) on Ubuntu 18.04.2. I've cloned it from git, installed all the dependencies (except zlib, which apt install doesn't find and I understand is included in zlib1g-dev).

When I try to `make` the tool, I get this:

```
$ make
make -C src/
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nextgen/src/schmutzi/src'
cd ../lib/bamtools// && mkdir -p build/  && cd build/ && cmake .. && make && cd ../../../src/
-- Checking for one of the modules 'jsoncpp>=1'
Did NOT find system JsonCpp, instead using bundled version
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY) (found version "1.2.11")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake:112 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
src/api/CMakeLists.txt:34 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/nextgen/src/schmutzi/lib/bamtools/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/nextgen/src/schmutzi/lib/bamtools/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:27: recipe for target 
'../lib/bamtools//build/src/api/libbamtools.a' failed
make[1]: *** [../lib/bamtools//build/src/api/libbamtools.a] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nextgen/src/schmutzi/src'
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'src/endoCaller' failed
make: *** [src/endoCaller] Error 2
```

I tried removing and reinstalling zlib. Zlib.h is in /usr/include/. It even says there is a version found. What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score -3):

You can install `zlib` via `sudo apt install zlib1g-dev`.